# jQuery easyui tree add rows to tree-title

Tags: jquery, tree, jquery-easyui

I am using jQuery plugin [easy-ui tree](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/tree.php).  Everything runs fine and the basic features were set up succesfully. So the basic looks like this [image]

So this displays the title of the file. But I want to add some more details beside the title. Lets say (just for the example), that I want to add details like Size, Created and Type. So it will look like this: [image]

I've tried to add some code to the javascript file called jquery.easyui.min.js which operates the plugin by managing the line for the 'tree-title'. But no success. Also modification of CSS didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploring, I've found the fastest, simplest and best option is to use the plugin **treegrid**  from the same company. So [here is the solution.](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/treegrid.php)

Hope that answers and helps everybody with the same question/issue.